# WebWorks app not opening on Verizon Bold 9650

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I've been working at this for hours and cannot for the life of me figure out why this is not working. I'm new with using WebWorks and developing for the BlackBerry so this may be a simple fix.

I have compiled a simple Hello, World page as index.html and created a config.xml with this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="1.0.0.0"> 

    <name>Test</name>
    <author>Me</author>
    <description>Testing</description>

    <content src="index.html"/> 

    <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog"/>
</widget>
```

I package it using bbwp and I get a .cod file with no problems. I can load this application on the simulator and the page shows up and says "Hello, World!". Obviously when I load this on the actual device, I get an error pertaining to accessing secure APIs.

Now, I have tried signing it using bbwp (I have set up my .csi file using the signature tool) and it says that it has signed correctly and a proper .cod is created. I load this on to the device using JavaLoader and it looks as if it has installed correctly. When I go to run the app on the device, nothing happens. No error messages, nothing pops up and there's no indication of anything happening. The signed .cod runs on the simulator just fine as well.

The BlackBerry is running OS 6.0.0.719 and is locked to Verizon. Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be or how I can solve this? Let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. I only installed one of the three .csi files. This was only partially signing the application and not allowing the application to start.